# Salesforce REST API Custom Settings

Tags: rest, api, salesforce

I need a service that retrieves all rows from a Custom Settings

I know I can use the standard REST API to retrieve a custom settings row but need to return **all** the rows with one call to the endpoint

```
<org>/services/data/v35.0/sobjects/<Custom Settings API Name>
```

Is there a way (a method?) I can use the above endpoint to return all rows or do I need to create a custom APEX service?

Answer (score 1):

Realized I can use the query method of the API; for example: `https://(orgid).salesforce.com/services/data/v29.0/query/?q=SELECT+fld1__c+,+fld2+from+(customsettingsAPI__c)`

This will return fld1 and fld2 for all rows from custom setting

Answer (score 0):

I was just looking to do the same thing,

look find this: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/49711/howto-wildcard-select-to-query-all-fields-of-objects-in-apex

An Example of api

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest_code_sample_basic.

good luck

Comment: I might be missing something in your answer but I know all the fields I need. Want I'm having issue with is how to get all the rows with one call to the  standard service `/services/data/v35.0/sobjects/<Custom Settings API Name>`.  I guess what I'll have to do is write my own service and use `@HttpGet`